# How to add an image to a point in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, image

How is it possible to add an image to a point in Qgis

I was thinking about something with html and actions

The following example is made by the plugin Qgis2web.
But the image wouldn't show. The image is stored in my documents;
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE stywax. Could you please supply an example of what you are referring to? What is your end goal?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want a webmap in the end or do you want to stay in QGIS?

Comment: at the end a webmap.
Makes that a difference?

Answer (score 2):

Right click the broken image and select properties. That should tell you the path where the webmap is looking for the image. Either copy your image to that location, or change the feature property in QGIS to the location of the image.